# Error saving high score using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am making a game using SpriteKit. The first time I lose the game, the high score is 0 (good). Then, I save the current score. The next time I play, the high score is a big number, for example 366508176. Why did this happens and any idea of how can I fix it?

This is  the ScoreScene.m file, it superclass is SKScene.
[GameScene getScore] is a static function that returns the last score.

```
//
//  ScoreScene.m
//

#import "ScoreScene.h"
#import "GameScene.h"
@interface ScoreScene()
@property BOOL contentCreated;
@end

@implementation ScoreScene
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    if (!self.contentCreated) {
        [self createSceneContents];
        self.contentCreated=YES;
    }
}

-(void)createSceneContents
{
    self.backgroundColor=[SKColor purpleColor];
    self.scaleMode=SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;


    NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int highScore=(int)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"HighScore"];
    //highScore is 0 the first time, 366508176 the second 

    int currentScore=[GameScene getScore];
    //currentScore is 3, for example
    if (currentScore>highScore) {

        [userDefaults setInteger:currentScore forKey:@"HighScore"];
        [userDefaults synchronize];
        highScore=currentScore;
    }
    [self addChild:[self newHighScoreLabel:highScore]];
    [self addChild:[self newScoreLabel]];
    [self addChild:[self newStartLabel]];
}


...




@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
int highScore=(int)[userDefaults objectForKey:@"HighScore"];
```

You need to do

```
int highScore = [userDefaults integerForKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Comment: It works!! objectForKey was the memory address or something similar?

Comment: ObjectForKey is when you write an object there - for example you could keep your score as NSNumber, than you use objectForKey

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:highScore forKey:@"HighScore"]
```

Get:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"HighScore"]
```

Comment: Mar 5 at 16:07 — accepted answer, Mar 5 at 16:13 — my answer, what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Or, it's a little more general purpose to "wrap" scalars in NSNumbers, which would give you:

```
[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

and

```
int HighScore = [[defaults objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue];
```

A benefit of this is that the object is now easily placed in collections, passed in notifications, etc.